# Selecting rows from Pandas Series where rows are arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to analyze US polling data, specifically, I'm trying to work out which States are safe, marginal, or tight ('closeness'). I have a dataframe with survey results by time and their 'closeness'. I'm using this Pandas statement to get a summary of the 'closeness' entries.

```
s=self.daily.groupby('State')['closeness'].unique()
```

This is giving me this series (selection shown for brevity):

```
State
AK                     [safe]
AL                     [safe]
CA                     [safe]
CO    [safe, tight, marginal]
FL          [marginal, tight]
IA    [safe, tight, marginal]
ID                     [safe]
IL                     [safe]
IN              [tight, safe]
Name: closeness, dtype: object
```

The rows are of type array, so, for example, `s[0]` gives:

```
array(['safe'], dtype=object)
```

I'm trying to select from this series, but I can't get the syntax right. For example, I'm trying to select just the 'safe' States using this syntax:

```
ipdb> s[s == 'safe']
*** ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

this doesn't work either:

```
test[test == ['safe'])
```

Here's what I'd like to do: select States that are 'marginal' or 'tight', select States that are 'safe' and only 'safe' and so on. Does anyone have any idea of the syntax I should use, or a better approach in the first place?

============
Here's a sample of the data before the groupby:

```
ipdb> self.daily.head(3)
        Date  Democratic share    Margin    Method  Other share  \

0 2008-11-04          0.378894 -0.215351  Election     0.026861   
1 2008-11-04          0.387404 -0.215765  Election     0.009427   
2 2008-11-04          0.388647 -0.198512  Election     0.024194   

   Republican share State closeness      winner  
0          0.594245    AK      safe  Republican  
1          0.603169    AL      safe  Republican
```

Comment: can  you post a sample data before doing `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks shivsn - added sample to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a DataFrame with a series of lists, say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [['safe'], ['safe', 'tight'], []]})
```

Then to see which ones are exactly safe, you can use:

```
In [7]: df.a.apply(lambda x: x == ['safe'])
Out[7]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

To find the ones which include safe, you can use:

```
 In [9]: df.a.apply(lambda x: 'safe' in x)
 Out[9]: 
 0     True
 1     True
 2    False
 Name: a, dtype: bool
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

dataframe sample given by OP :

```
In[66]:df
Out[66]: 
         Date  Democratic share    Margin    Method  Other share  0  2008-11-04          0.378894 -0.215351  Election     0.026861   
1  2008-11-04          0.387404 -0.215765  Election     0.009427   
2  2008-11-04          0.388647 -0.198512  Election     0.024194   
3  2008-11-04          0.384547 -0.194545  Election     0.024194   
4  2008-11-04          0.345330 -0.194512  Election     0.024459   

   Republican share State closeness      winner  
0          0.594245    AK      safe  Republican  
1          0.603169    AL      safe  Republican  
2          0.454545    CA     tight  Democratic  
3          0.453450    CO  marginal  Democratic  
4          0.454545    FL     tight    Republic
```

then by using grupby:

```
In[67]:s=df.groupby('State')['closeness'].unique()

In[68]:s
Out[68]: 
State
AK        [safe]
AL        [safe]
CA       [tight]
CO    [marginal]
FL       [tight]
```

then using [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In[69]:s.ix[np.where(s=='safe')]
Out[69]: 
State
AK    [safe]
AL    [safe]
Name: closeness, dtype: object
```

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso No it doesn't if you go by the op's way he's getting a series with array of values, I'll update the answer .

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120309/selecting-rows-from-pandas-series-where-rows-are-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

I think constructing the series `s` by using `.unique()` is not the best way of attacking this problem. Try using `pd.crosstab` instead.

```
import pandas as pd

daily = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['AK', 'AL', 'CA', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'FL',
                                'FL', 'IA', 'IA', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IN'],
                      'closeness': ['safe', 'safe', 'safe', 'safe', 'tight',
                                    'marginal', 'marginal', 'tight', 'safe',
                                    'tight', 'marginal', 'safe', 'safe',
                                    'tight', 'safe']})
ct = pd.crosstab(daily['State'], daily['closeness'])
print(ct)
```

Output:

```
closeness  marginal  safe  tight
State                           
AK                0     1      0
AL                0     1      0
CA                0     1      0
CO                1     1      1
FL                1     0      1
IA                1     1      1
ID                0     1      0
IL                0     1      0
IN                0     1      1
```

One the one hand, this `ct` contains exactly the same information as your `s`; on the other, it makes it trivial to select states the way you want. The two examples you proposed:

```
# states that are 'marginal' or 'tight'
print(ct.loc[(ct['marginal'] > 0) | (ct['tight'] > 0)]
        .index.values)
# => ['CO', 'FL', 'IA', 'IN']

# States that are 'safe' and only 'safe'
print(ct.loc[(ct['safe'] > 0) & (ct['marginal'] == 0) & (ct['tight'] == 0)]
        .index.values)
# => ['AK', 'AL', 'CA', 'ID', 'IL']
```

Or, using the perhaps more readable `.query()`:

```
# states that are 'marginal' or 'tight'
print(ct.query('marginal > 0 | tight > 0').index.values)
# => ['CO', 'FL', 'IA', 'IN']

# States that are 'safe' and only 'safe'
print(ct.query('safe > 0 & marginal == 0 & tight == 0')
        .index.values)
# => ['AK', 'AL', 'CA', 'ID', 'IL']
```

Yet if you insist on using your `s`, here is how you can construct `ct` from it:

```
ct = s.str.join(' ').str.get_dummies(sep=' ')
```